# RewriteCond for APIKEY

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, httpd, rewritecond

I am trying to create a RewriteRule which looks at the incoming Header for an `APIKey` and if it contains a matching string then it will redirect to respective URL else, it should be inaccessible.

I am testing this scenario using postman with Post method.

Please find my code below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/manager/(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/manager/secure/rest/groovy-service-invoke/v2/demo/firewall-test/v0.1.0/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{ENV:APIKEY}   ^ABCD123456789$
RewriteRule .* - [E:APIKEY=ABCD123456789]
```

Answer (score 0):

To block access (ie. 403 Forbidden) to any URL-path that starts `/manager/` when the HTTP request header `APIKey` is not supplied with the specific value (eg. `ABCD123456789`) you can use the following mod_rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:APIKey} !=ABCD123456789
RewriteRule ^/?manager/ - [F]
```

---

> ```
> :
> RewriteCond %{ENV:APIKEY}   ^ABCD123456789$
> RewriteRule .* - [E:APIKEY=ABCD123456789]
> ```

This isn't actually doing anything. It sets the environment variable `APIKEY` to the value `ABCD123456789` but only when the env var `APIKEY` is already set to that value!